# Teradata Convert Integer to a timestamp

Tags: date, teradata

I am trying to select data from a table that has a date range
Its a bit messy as its being passed from JAVA as an integer of the form 20160101 (YYYYMMDD)

So basically i want to be able to run a query like (incidentally this is the type of time stamp that works in the query)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A as t
WHERE t_timestamp >='2016-10-01 00:00:00'
```

I have looked around on google and SO and have come up with something like this

```
SELECT CAST(20161001 AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 00:00:00'
```

This is to try and convert the integer number to time stamp that will be acceptable as a date range. This doesn't appear to work. There is no error, just that results for when i statically add the time stamp exist vs when i try and make it general don't exist

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have as character value below query should work
    sel (CAST('20161001' AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyymmdd')(format 'yyyy-mm-dd')(char(10)))|| ' 00:00:00'

Below query converts the value to timestamp(0)

```
sel cast((CAST('20161001' AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyymmdd')(format 'yyyy-mm-dd')(char(10)))|| ' 00:00:00' as timestamp(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the result of `SELECT CAST(20161001 AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')`? It returns `'3916-10-01'` and you probably don't have data like tghat :-)

Apply a typecast to a string and then cast to a date:

```
WHERE t_timestamp >= Cast(Trim(20161001) AS DATE Format 'YYYYMMDD')
```